# Can I trigger a jQuery set cookie from a forwarded domain?

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

Potentially have a multilanguage site whereby the language is translated by toggling HTML div classes by using jQuery links which in turn then sets a cookie to keep the language the same across the site.

jQuery below:

```
    $(function() {
    $("a.langSelect").click(function() {
        var language = $(this).text();
        $("div#masterLangauge").removeClass().addClass(language);
        createCookie("language",language);
        return false;
    });

    if (readCookie("language") != null) {
      $("div#masterLangauge").removeClass().addClass(readCookie("language"));

    }
    else
    {
      $("div#masterLangauge").removeClass().addClass("english");
    }

});

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

HTML of  links are below:

```
<a class="langSelect" href="#">english</a
<a class="langSelect" href="#">deutsch</a>
<a class="langSelect" href="#">chinese</a>
```

HTML div which is toggled is below, default is english - if German is selected the class changes to German

```
<div id="masterLangauge" class="english">
```

Then using CSS I will then hide all other languages using display: none and display:block the german language. This works fine at the moment which is great.

What I need to know is if a referring/localised domain name forwards through to the site can I trigger this jQuery cookie and functions?

So we have the domain name **example.com**, if we have the domain name **germanexample.com** redirect to **example.com** I would like the cookie and language choice to be in German and not the default English. Can jQuery handle forwarded domains or is there a way I can use PHP to create a similar desired effect?

I hope this is clear and makes sense, quite a difficult thing to explain...

Thanks in advance everybody.

Comment: You could use the Referrer or set a custom HTTP Header on the redirecting server and read this header with JS on the other domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's easiest if you add a `#hash` to the referred URL and then handle the cookies there at the referred to domain.

So on germanexample.com your link/referral would be example.com#lang=german
Then on example.com you can check for hash existence

```
var getHashValue = function(key) {
    if (typeof key !== 'string') {
        key = '';
    } else {
        key = key.toLowerCase();
    }

    var keyAndHash = location.hash.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp(key + '=([^&]*)'));
    var value = '';

    if (keyAndHash) {
        value = keyAndHash[1];
    }

    return value;
};

if(getHashValue('lang')){
  //setCookie.... etc etc.
} else {
  // readCookie etc.
}
```

it must be noted though that this may not work in your favour for Search engine optimisation as the crawlers mostly do not execute javascript and hence the german version of google will still be hitting the page with english, german and chinese text.